# SQL Two foreign keys linked to one primary key of another table to pull field from that table

Tags: sql

The question title is probably confusing so I'll try to clear it up.

I have two columns in a grid. State and Locality.
I have two foreign keys in a table.  Notification.fkState and Notification.fkLocality.
They are both linked to the primary key of another table.  Location.pkLocation
I want the ALIASES of State and Locality to equal the Location.Name from the Location Table according to the foreign key value linked the primary key pkLocation.

Is there a statement like

`SELECT Location.Name(WHERE Notification.fkState=Location.pkLocation) AS State, Location.Name(WHERE Notification.fkLocality=Location.pkLocation) AS Locality FROM Notification INNER JOIN Locality ON Notification.fkState=Location.pkLocation AND Notification.fkLocality=Location.pkLocation`

My AND is currently an OR because when it is AND...it displays nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Have you missed part of the query? Sorry, or have you *ever* written SQL before?

Comment: I've written out the whole thing, I just didn't share the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT S.Name AS Locality, N.Name AS State
From Notification N
Inner Join Location S on N.fkstate=S.pkLocation
Inner Join Location L on  N.fkLocality=L.pkLocation
```

Comment: But I need to have aliases for State and Locality within the statement if Location.Type=1 it's a state, and if Location.Type=2 it's a locality

Comment: Do you have any state column in any table ?

Comment: I have a grid with a state column and a locality column but for now, because I have no aliases, i just call the Location field for both so of course it displays the same data

Comment: But it needs to be able to differentiate when Location.Type=1 that's the state column, or Type=2 is a locailty

Comment: example:  When I do Notification.fkState AS State I get the number for state.  but what I want is the Name that corresponds with that Number from the Location Table. so if 30 is Florida.  Then the above code outputs 30.  I want it to take that value and pull the name from the Location table. While at the same time pulling the name for Miami as Locality.

Comment: I was thinking like: Location.Name(WHERE Notification.fkState=Location.pkLocation) AS State, Location.Name(WHERE Notification.fkLocality=Location.pkLocation) AS Locality

Comment: You mean state info is in Notification and locality in location ?

Comment: No, the foreign keys are both in Notification. (Notification.fkState and Notification.fkLocality)  Both values correspond to Location.pkLocation which also has a Location.Name.  I want to display the appropriate Name for those foreign keys from the Location table

Comment: Please send teh schema of your table and update it in your question

Comment: Any Update for the above answer ?

Comment: That worked and it's excellent!  Just fix the upper part to: L.Name AS Locality, S.Name AS State